# How to find on which CPU&Core my thread is running

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, winapi, hpc

I have an app that use HPC, and it automatically assign each thread to specific CPU and Cores on the HPC.
I would like to know to which CPU and Core my thread is assigned to.

[GetCurrentProcessorNumber](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683181.aspx) return the Core ID which my thread is run on, and I wish to know on which CPU it runs as well.

My HPC has at least 2 CPU's and 10 cores on each CPU

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: May I suggest you read [ask] before your next question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3367070/1870760 threads switch cores.

Comment: Thanks @dandan78. 
Can you please mention which part can be improved?

Comment: Thanks @GillBates - I found it useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Identify processor (core) is used by specific thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366932/identify-processor-core-is-used-by-specific-thread)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check the [GetCurrentProcessorNumber](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683181.aspx) API (or [GetCurrentProcessorNumberEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd405487.aspx) if you have more than 64 logical processors).

Comment: Thanks, that has solved one issue I have.
Do you know how can I get the CPU the thread is run on?

Comment: Just divide by the number of cores/cpu and keep the integer result.