# Get the ID of the currently executing CPU on M1

Tags: multithreading, macos, apple-m1

Is there a way to get a unique ID for the core that is executing the current thread?

On OSX x86, the `cpuid` CPU instruction [could be used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33745364/149138) but that doesn't work on Apple Silicon like the M1 which is based on ARMv8.